# Moving HTTP site to HTTPS on Netlify - 301 Redirects and SEO

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, netlify, http-redirect

I am moving my old HTTP site to Netlify and need some guidance on 301 redirects and SEO.

I will be using netlify.toml for redirects.

Netlify will automatically redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com so I'm assuming that a redirect rule is not needed for this case.

**Question 1:** For http://example.com to https://www.example.com - should I do this in DNS or 301 redirect rule in netlify.toml?

For the following URL

http://www.example.com/directory/page1.html

**Question 2:** Should I use relative or absolute URLs to redirect? Which from below would be a best-case scenario?

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/directory/page1.html"
  to = "https://www.example.com/directory/:splat"
  status = 301
  force = true
  
 [[redirects]]
  from = "http://www.example.com/directory/page1.html"
  to = "https://www.example.com/directory/:splat"
  status = 301
  force = true
```